# Share cookie between differents ports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if it is possible to share the coockies of an application that is running on one port to another application that is running on another port.
As additional data I use node js and express as a library to create the server and coockie-session

Comment: No. Cookies are not shared between different domains, and each port is considered a different domain.

Comment: The server software is irrelevant, it's the browser that decides whether to send the cookie to the server.